# How to check if a variable contains a character not found in a list within a BASH conditional?

Tags: bash

I need to create a BASH conditional that checks if any unusual characters are found. If any character is not one of these, the conditional returns true: `c`, `d`, `f`, `g`, `h`, `T`, `,`, `?`, `!`. E.g.:

```
if [[ "$variable" contains something that is not [cdfghZ,?!] ]]
then
    echo "The variable contains an unknown character."
fi
```

How can I check for characters not found in a list with a BASH conditional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `globbing`:

```
[[ "$variable" == *[^cdfghT,?\!]* ]]
```

**PS:** `!` needs to be used as `\!` to escape history event expansion.

Comment: alternative: `[[ $variable =~ [^cdfghT,?\!] ]]`

Comment: The string `aha` returns false for the condition, even if it "contains something that is not [cdfghZ,?!]".

Comment: Yes instead of globbing using regex we can use `~` operator also.

Comment: Actually I interpreted conditions reverse. Corrected now.

Comment: `!` only needs to be escaped if history expansion is turned on, which is only the default in interactive shells.

Answer (score 4):

Good old `case` has this built in, and is portable to all Bourne shells.

```
case $variable in *[!cdfghZ,?!]* ) 
    echo "The variable contains an unknown character." >&2 ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check with a regular expression:

```
 if [[ $variable =~ [^cdfghT,?\!] ]] ; then
 ...
```

Comment: This will fail if $variable contains a string with whitespaces

Comment: @user3755692: How would it fail?

Comment: it would fail if `$variable` would be a string like `a b c d e f` - you need to write `"$variable"` instead

Comment: @user3755692: Have you tried it? It's not true. It holds for `[ ... ]` conditions, but not for `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: I get two errors: 1.) `bash: conditional binary operator expected` and 2.) `bash: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort 'b'`

Comment: @user3755692: What version of bash do you run? It works for me (4.1)

Comment: `$BASH_VERSION` contains `4.2.37(1)-release`

Comment: @user3755692: Can you show the exact commands (both the variable assignment and the condition)?

Comment: `$ if [[ a b c =~ [a-z ]+ ]]; then echo "hallo"; fi`

Comment: @user3755692: There's no variable. For literals, you have to use quotes or backslash the spaces, of course.

Comment: `$ variable="a b c"; if [[ $variable =~ [a-z ]+ ]]; then echo "hallo"; fi` fails as well with a syntax error

Comment: @user3755692: Sure. But adding double quotes around $variable doesn't help.

Comment: Oh I see it doesn't help, but is there no solution to use a regex on an input string containing whitespacs in bash?

Comment: @user3755692: You must backslash the space in the regex: `[[ $variable =~ [a-z\ ]+ ]]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use extended patterns (which are used by default inside `[[...]]` in `bash` 4.2 but need to be explicitly enabled in earlier versions):

```
shopt -s extglob  # if necessary
if [[ $variable != +([cdfghZ,?!]) ]]; then
```

The pattern `+(...)` matches a string containing one or more characters, each of which must match the pattern inside the parentheses. It is essentially equivalent to the regular expression `[cdfghZ,?!]+`.